# Rotate Figure using sidewaysfigure according to page number

Tags: tables, floats, rotating

I have a lot of tables and figures to include in my thesis. I am using sidewaysfigure to include them in a full-page landscape view. I need to put 90 degrees-oriented figures if the page is on the left side (even page number) and -90 degrees-oriented figures if the page is on the right side (odd page number). With the code below I obtain random orientation with no respect to the page number. In the code below you'll find 3 important examples for my theis corresponding to 1 figure and 2 tables all of them put in sidewaysfigure environment. Is there any solution obtain what I want ? Note that I haven't know how to separate the LaTex code with the text in this forum.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english,french]{book}
.....
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
.....
\begin{document}
.....
..... % Figure 1:
\begin{sidewaysfigure}[!htbp] 
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm,font={small}}
\centering
\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=.7]{imagesP/test.eps}}
\caption{Localisation géographique}
\captionsetup{font={scriptsize}}
\label{Figure:Local}
\caption*{{Conception de l'auteur,  Données S.I.G: \ac{OTEDD} [2013]}}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
....
% Table 1 (Part 1/2 of the table divided into to pages)
\begin{sidewaystable}[!htbp] 
\footnotesize
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.8cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.4cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.5cm} X}
\hline
\textbf{Année} & {\textbf{Auteur}} & {\textbf{Article}} & {\textbf{Revue}} &  \centering{\textbf{Apport théorique / empirique}} \tabularnewline
\hline
Text & Text & Text & Text \\
\hline
Text & Text & Text & Text \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm,font={small}}
\caption{Chronologie des études (1/2)}
\captionsetup{font={scriptsize}}
\label{sec3:chrono}
\caption*{Source: Conception de l'auteur}
\end{sidewaystable}
% Table 2 (Part 2/2 of the table divided into to pages)
\begin{sidewaystable}[!htbp] 
\footnotesize
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.8cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.4cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.5cm} X}
\hline
\textbf{Année} & {\textbf{Auteur}} & {\textbf{Article}} & {\textbf{Revue}} &  \centering{\textbf{Apport théorique / empirique}} \tabularnewline
\hline
Text & Text & Text & Text \\
\hline
Text & Text & Text & Text \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm,font={small}}
\caption{Chronologie des études (2/2)}
\captionsetup{font={scriptsize}}
\label{sec3:chrono2}
\caption*{Source: Conception de l'auteur}
\end{sidewaystable}
....
\end{document}
```

Comment: My opinion is that the rotation shouldn't depend on the side of the page. If you always rotate 90 degrees counterclockwise, the reader will always have to rotate the book 90 degrees clockwise.

Comment: I don't think a reader will find suitable a figure oriented 90 degrees counterclockwise in the right side (odd page number). This have no sens.

Comment: Well, everybody is entitled their own opinion.

Comment: @user40953 egreg's comment makes sense. Imagine if you have one image on an even-numbered page and another related image on the following (odd-numbered) page. The reader won't be able to see both images at the same time (for comparison purposes, perhaps) but will have to flip the book over.

Comment: @Jubobs Yes! You have right on this case. But I do not have figures included successively on 2 pages in my thesis. I just want to avoid the case where the figure is oriented 90 degrees counterclockwise in the right side (odd page number). You could say \usepackage[figuresleft]{rotating} may resolve the problem but with this I will not obtain -90 degrees-oriented figures if the page is on the right side (odd page number). Is there any kind of \figuresleft or \figuresright commands to each separate figures ?