# How to swap or invert the behavior of 'sidewaysfigure' from package 'rotating'?

Tags: rotating, sidewaysfigurepage

For the `book` class, *by default* the package [`rotating`](https://ctan.org/pkg/rotating?lang=en) will rotate an instance of the environment `sidewaysfigure`

- counterclockwise by 90 degrees if the floating page lands on an odd page number, or
- clockwise by 90 degrees if the floating page lands on an even page number.

So, for instance this is the default output

[image: Example output]

of the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure} \LARGE
    Should be: from UP to DOWN. But is: from DOWN to UP.
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\newpage

\begin{sidewaysfigure} \LARGE
    Should be: from DOWN to UP. But is: from UP to DOWN.
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

***Q:*** How could I invert/swap the default behavior?

The hope is that if the figure lands on an even page, then its rotated counterclockwise; if on an odd page, then clockwise. This makes more sense to me since even page numbers are usually the left-hand page of a book, and odd page numbers are the right-hand page.

The package options `figuresleft` and `figuresright` do not work here. They remove chirality-dependence altogether whereas I would like to swap/invert the default behaviour. Note that I do not have a great many of these pages, so "neck pain" is not a problem. If you don't recognize what "neck pain" is referring to here, you may ignore this explanation :).

Comment: These questions are related but are not duplicates: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146413/rotate-figure-using-sidewaysfigure-according-to-page-number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146413/116907), [Change rotations with sidewaysfigure and twoside option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410796/116907), [Inconsistent rotations with \sidewaysfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93924/116907).

Comment: I've always considered sidewaysfigure to be nearly pointless.  All you neeed is a minipage and rotatebox (graphicx) with a normal figure to achieve the same effect  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399557/place-a-sidewaysfigure-correctly-in-a-two-column-document/399591?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C15.2052#399591 for example..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You can patch the command to negate the `\ifodd` test.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\end@rotfloat
{\isodd{\R@@page}}
{\not{\isodd{\R@@page}}}
{}%
{}%

\let\endsidewaysfigure\end@rotfloat
\let\endsidewaystable\end@rotfloat
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure} \LARGE
    Should be: from UP to DOWN. But is: from DOWN to UP.
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\newpage

\begin{sidewaysfigure} \LARGE
    Should be: from DOWN to UP. But is: from UP to DOWN.
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Although Overleaf warns that there is an [```invalid environment command```](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXXLy.png), compiling the code gives no warnings or errors.

Comment: complain to overleaf about that:-)

Comment: (Tom from Overleaf Support here) You can add `%%begin novalidate` before `\makeatletter` and `%%end novalidate` after `\makeatother` to make the linter shut up for that part. (Note that this extra code needs to be on lines of its own.) I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks @yo'.....

Comment: @yo' I was two clicks away from submitting the academic complaint. Just checked back to retrieve link to the answer and picture. Maybe next time then! :)